# Required capabilities when running BrowserStack Automate with a mobile device

Tags: webdriver, automated-tests, browserstack

**Description**
The [BrowserStack documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities) lists all capabilities you can set for their Automate product but does not describe which ones MUST be present in order to test on, for example a 'Google Nexus 5'.

[Their code generator](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#setting-os-and-browser) suggests this:

```
{
   "browserName" : "android",
   "platform" : "ANDROID",
   "device" : "Google Nexus 5"
}
```

But I know from experience that this set of capabilities also works:

```
{"os":"android", "device": "Google Nexus 5"}
```

Because of this I'm asking myself:

**Question**
Does `{"device": "Google Nexus 5"}` also work?
And if not, what is the minimum and correct set of capabilities when using BrowserStack Automate with a specific mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you request a webdriver session with only the capability 'device' set, BrowserStack will successfully create a session on that device with the default browser of the device.

Source: E-Mail conversation with a kind BrowserStack technical Support employee.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the code generator by BrowserStack. This ensures you have the correct environment for the test.